# Python tkFileDialog.askdirectory error

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

i have a following code in python

```
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
top=Tkinter.Tk()
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=top)
```

when i print the dirname it appears as normal,and gives

```
F:/Project/Dropbox/My Mtech Main Project/Programming Folder/SPIDER/Ubuntu Spyder/
```

But when i acess the dirname,otherwise, ie.. like type dirname in command windows i got the following output,

```
    u"F:/Project/Dropbox/My Mtech Main Project/Programming Folder/SPIDER/Ubuntu Spyder/"
```

How can i avoid this u ,so that i can use the dirname as an input to another operation like, read a wavefile etc. Now i got the error becuase of that u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the `u` before the `path` is just to show that the string is of `unicode type`

you can check the `type` of `data` by using the function `type(data)` (check for `dirname`)

```
Unicode strings are expressed as instances of the unicode type
one of Python's repertoire of built-in types
```

more information [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

In case you want to avoid this just change the type.

```
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
top=Tkinter.Tk()
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
dirname = str(tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=top))
```

hope that helps